# What is the most reliable tumour suppressing gene for NSCLC?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, cancer

I was looking at some tumour suppressing genes that can be helpful in diagnosing lung cancer (particularly NSCLC - Non-small-cell lung carcinoma) at an early stage. I came across a few such as p53, etc. However, as a beginner (and someone who has never pursued higher studies in biology), I do not have much knowledge as to which is the most reliable and the most extensively documented tumour suppressing gene for NSCLC.

Comment: Welcome to Biology SE! I took the liberty to edit your question to resolve the abbreviation. You can revert my edit any time if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first resource I would look at would be the TCGA publication on NSCLC which can be found at [this location](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature13385). The first figure shows the most frequently mutated genes. TP53 rises to the top as most frequently mutated gene in the cohort studied, however, one also sees on the list KEAP1, NF1, ARID1A, SMARCA4, RB1, and CDKN2 as commonly altered tumor suppressors TSGs. You will want to take into account copy number data and mutation data in the frequency count in cohort also. Another issue to check in the data set is stage of the tumors in TCGA. You mentioned 'early stage' in your query, but if all the samples in TCGA are recurrent then it may not be appropriate for your question. The cBioPortal resource allows you to look and manipulate the data and I encourage you to look at that resource. It is very well done and shouldn't have too much of a learning curve. You will be able to put in TSGs and get back the freq of mutations. They may also have information on stage so might be possible to filter for only those samples. There are also a couple of text-mining resources that you can ask queries through pubmed to get back gene lists or to link gene lists. One tool is Glad4U (search this name in google) which allows you to type a query such as: "tumor suppressor AND early stage NSCLC" and it will return a ranked list of genes. Ranking is based on co-citation. However, one must check the returned list to make sure the genes returned are TSGs. A listing of putative TSGs can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JFUFg10UX8vxZ0hMbYIKHoceJJ7dzeDW8xbus9q-kyk/edit#gid=1679505956). The second resource is CoCiter v2.0. On the Gene-Term search you can rank the lists of TSGs against search terms and it will return a ranking of the TSGs most associated with your search term. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was looking for such an answer for a long time. I'll go through all the sources that you have listed